# how to add an entry into final list by jolt map to list

Tags: java, json, jolt

I'm trying to transform a map to list by Jolt, which is done ok
the problem is that I need to add an entry as a default(not in input schema)
but it doesn't work

I have a simple schema as is:

```json
{
  "iban": "IR970130100000000000001399",
  "paymentCode": "124"
}
```

and except the output like this:

```json
{
  "parameters": [
    {
      "name": "iban",
      "value": "IR970130100000000000001399"
    },
    {
      "name": "paymentCode",
      "value": "124"
    },
    {
      "name": "P_RQID",
      "value": "4f2ba174-690f-4d41-9bcc-b958789fe6d7"
    }
  ]
}
```

this is my spec:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "$": "parameters.[#2].name",
        "@": "parameters.[#2].value"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "parameters": {
        "name": "P_RQID",
        "value": "4f2ba174-690f-4d41-9bcc-b958789fe6d7"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

and this is the output I have:

```json
{
  "parameters": [
    {
      "name": "iban",
      "value": "IR970130100000000000001399"
    },
    {
      "name": "paymentCode",
      "value": "124"
    }
  ]
}
```

without the effect of default operation.
anyone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might change the order of the transformations while adding `"parameters"` case along with the else case( `"*"` ) to the shift transformation spec such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "parameters": {
        "name": "P_RQID",
        "value": "4f2ba174-690f-4d41-9bcc-b958789fe6d7"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "parameters": "&",
      "*": { // non-parameters case
        "$": "parameters[#2].name",
        "@": "parameters[#2].value"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :

[image]

Comment: that's fine
thanks Barbaros

Comment: Welcome to SO @MehdiAbniki

Comment: thanks for your attention @BarbarosOzhan
where can I find such deep guide for Jolt?

Comment: @MehdiAbniki There are some sources which I like ;[1](https://erbalvindersingh.medium.com/applying-jolttransform-on-json-object-array-and-fetching-specific-fields-48946870b4fc), [2](https://intercom.help/godigibee/en/articles/3096940-simple-if-else-with-jolt), [3](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/Jolt-quick-reference-for-Nifi-Jolt-Processors/ta-p/244350), [4](https://cool-cheng.blogspot.com/2019/12/json-jolt-tutorial.html)

Comment: and you can check out the [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jolt/info) stated within SO @MehdiAbniki