# Jolt spect improve

Tags: json, jolt

as I new in jolt and next to the previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76867922/how-to-add-an-entry-into-final-list-by-jolt-map-to-list#comment135512163_76868009) I'm trying to add some more steps.

again from the input as this

```json
{
  "iban": "IR970130100000000000001399",
  "paymentCode": "124"
}
```

I want to have such output

```json
{
  "parameters": [
    {
      "name": "P_IBAN",
      "value": "IR970130100000000000001399"
    },
    {
      "name": "P_PAYMENTCODE",
      "value": "124"
    },
    {
      "name": "P_RQID",
      "value": "4f2ba174-690f-4d41-9bcc-b958789fe6d7"
    },
    {
      "name": "P_TYPEX",
      "value": "1"
    },
    {
      "name": "P_BIC",
      "value": "1"
    }
  ],
  "requestID": "RequestID",
  "callType": "Reader",
  "encoding": "ASCII"
}
```

the steps are as:

1. add multi entry in default spec
2. add P_  prefix to "name" of input (transform to p_name)
3. transform p_name to uppercase

this is the spec I have

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "parameters": {        
        "name": "P_RQUD",
        "value": "4f2ba174-690f-4d41-9bcc-b958789fe6d7"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "parameters": "&",
      "*": {
        "$": "parameters[#2].name",
        "@": "parameters[#2].value"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "parameters": {
        "*": {
          "name": "=toUpper"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "callType": "Reader",
      "encoding": "ASCII",
      "requestID": "RequestID"
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the first **`"parameter"`** node to an array key while getting rid of the last **default** transformation spec, as enough to use **`#`** prefixes on the LHS to generate fixed key-value pairs within a **shift** transformation spec such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "parameters": [
        {
          "name": "RQUD",
          "value": "4f2ba174-690f-4d41-9bcc-b958789fe6d7"
        },
        {
          "name": "TYPEX",
          "value": "1"
        },
        {
          "name": "BIC",
          "value": "1"
        }
     ]
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "parameters": { "*": "&1" }, //&1 copies the literal value "parameters" after traversing 1 level above
      "*": {
        "$": "parameters[#2].name",
        "@": "parameters[#2].value"
      },
      "#RequestID": "requestID",
      "#Reader": "callType",
      "#ASCII": "encoding"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "parameters": {
        "*": {
          "n": "=toUpper(@(1,name))",
          "name": "=concat('P_',@(1,n))"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // get rid of the newly generated extra attribute
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "parameters": {
        "*": {
          "n": ""
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // sorts the elements alphabetically as default
    "operation": "sort"
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :

[image]

Comment: Hi barbaros;
I've added below line
{
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "parameters": {
        "*": {
          "name": "=toUpper"
        }
      }
    }
  }
to uppercase the names, and the last thing is to add (P_) prefix to first two entry
(IBAN -> P_IBAN)
thanks for your help as before and next

Comment: that's fine
Thanks @BarbarosOzhan again

Comment: as I'm new here, please let me know what I did with your answer, till now, is ok or I should do more?