# Jolt server side data manipulation/convertion

Tags: java, json, jolt

As next step from the last [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76888279/jolt-spect-improve/76888344#76888344) , I have an special issue on Jolt

By consider the input schema as:

```
{
  "iban": "IR970130100000000000001399",
  "paymentCode": "124"
}
```

and the spec as:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "parameters": [
        {
          "name": "ACCOUNT",
          "value": "convertedIBAN"
        },
        {
          "name": "RQUD",
          "value": "4f2ba174-690f-4d41-9bcc-b958789fe6d7"
        },
        {
          "name": "TYPEX",
          "value": "1"
        },
        {
          "name": "BIC",
          "value": "1"
        }
     ]
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "parameters": { "*": "&1" },
      "*": {
        "$": "parameters[#2].name",
        "@": "parameters[#2].value"
      },
      "#RequestID": "requestID",
      "#Reader": "callType",
      "#ASCII": "encoding"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "parameters": {
        "*": {
          "n": "=toUpper(@(1,name))",
          "name": "=concat('P_',@(1,n))"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "parameters": {
        "*": {
          "n": ""
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

I have the below output:

```
{
  "requestID" : "RequestID",
  "callType" : "Reader",
  "encoding" : "ASCII",
  "parameters" : [ {
    "name" : "P_IBAN",
    "value" : "IR970130100000000000001399"
  }, {
    "name" : "P_PAYMENTCODE",
    "value" : "124"
  }, {
    "name" : "P_ACCOUNT",
    "value" : "convertedIBAN"
  }, {
    "name" : "P_RQUD",
    "value" : "4f2ba174-690f-4d41-9bcc-b958789fe6d7"
  }, {
    "name" : "P_TYPEX",
    "value" : "1"
  }, {
    "name" : "P_BIC",
    "value" : "1"
  } ]
}
```

In next, I need to change the value of P_Account(as is 'convertedIBAN') to a new one, but this value should be
retrieve from DB by the value of iban from input schema(which is 'IR970130100000000000001399').
To do so, I think I should have a Jolt method(in Jolt core or somewhere) to do this job.
I have an idea same as what's going on with "=toUpper..." and "=concat...", with the name such as "=convert..." or "=fetch...) but go through the DB communication in background